Why GitHub Actions shell don't let me use `let` or `((++))` with a variable equal to 0?
I am using a GitHub Action with steps using ubuntu-latest default shell (bash 5.11 the time of writing).
However, I find inconsistencies with my local bash (5.12) when running the script and a variable is 0.
Specifically, the GHA fails (exit code 1) with:

let my_var=0, but not let my_var=42,
((my_var++)) when my_var is 0, but not when it is 42.

What causes this?
Example GHA:
name: Test shell
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test-shell:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Increment variable
        run: |
          let my_var=3
          echo "::notice::my_var is $my_var"
          ((my_var++))
          echo "::notice::my_var is now $my_var"

      - name: FAIL - Set variable to 0 using let
        if: false
        run: |
          echo "::notice::Preparing to initialize variable to 0"
          let my_var=0
          echo "::notice::my_var is $my_var"

      - name: Set variable to 0
        run: |
          echo "::notice::Preparing to initialize variable to 0"
          my_var=0
          echo "::notice::my_var is $my_var"

      - name: FAIL - Increment variable from 0 using ((++))
        if: false
        run: |
          my_var=0
          echo "::notice::my_var is $my_var"
          ((my_var++))
          echo "::notice::my_var is now $my_var"

      - name: Increment variable from 0 using +=
        run: |
          my_var=0
          echo "::notice::my_var is $my_var"
          let my_var+=1
          echo "::notice::my_var is now $my_var"


The let keyword invokes arithmetic evaluation, which causes the statement (and thus the script, with set -e) to fail when it's zero.
Anyway, here, the let keyword isn't providing any value; just use a regular shell variable assignment my_var=0 which doesn't incur an arithmetic evaluation.
The set -e is implicit; it is activated by Github Actions to terminate the action if a script fails.
Perhaps see also What does 'set -e' mean in a Bash script?
